# What caused reputation to be out of sync (back in the old days?)

Tags: discussion, reputation

There used to be a <kbd>Trigger Reputation Recalc</kbd> button on the `/reputation` page back in < 2013. Later on it was removed, after an update made it so that reputation recalcs were no longer necessary.

I was wondering, how could your reputation possibly get out of sync?

---

I don't understand how deleted posts would make a difference, as deleting a post simply takes back the reputation lost or gained from it.

And the 200-per-day reputation limit? How is that going to make a difference? Obviously reputation recalcs **do** take the reputation cap into account, right?

Comment: _"I was wondering, how could your reputation possibly get out of sync?"_ Server side caching!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before the automated recalculation systems which are in place today existed, recalculations never occurred. Ever. When posts were deleted, you kept all the reputation until some global recalculation event was triggered (rarely happened, think about once per year) or you manually did it yourself. If something messed up, it never got corrected. Many users had incorrect reputation numbers because of events long past which were never calculated into their score, ranging from just a few to thousands.

Nowadays, we have such a system. Any time something happens with your account that would require your reputation to be recalculated (a deletion/undeletion, user deletion, whatever) your profile gets scheduled to be recalculated by the system. Whenever the system checks again for profiles to be recalculated (every ~15 minutes), it grabs the list of all scheduled profiles and recalculates them all automatically without the need for any manual process.

The button was removed shortly after this new system was implemented because users were using it to manually recalculate their profiles when bugs would occur and it was essentially hiding those bugs, making it harder for developers to figure out what was going wrong so it could be fixed. Since the new system was meant to make such a button obsolete and useless, there was no reason for it to stick around and allow it to cause more problems.

Answer (score 6):

Simply put, not everything that might affect the reputation number updated it in real-time.

Performing a recalc caused the system to start from the beginning of time (when you first created your account), and walked through all of the changes in chronological order until it arrived at the present moment, at which time it updated your displayed reputation (cached in the database as a single number).

Nowadays, there is enough real-time integration so that such recalcs are seldom required, though they do still occur occasionally.